# Display Azure Insights on an external website

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have a main website which is making use of Azure Insights to get statistics and information concerning what the users are doing. I am able to see all these activities from the Azure Portal (sessions, users flows, etc...), however I also have an admin dashboard website that controls activities for the main website and I would like to display some of the information gathered in Azure over there. Is there any way to retrieve them or are they limited to be seen inside the Azure Portal? For example is there an API or a way to retrieve the "User Flows" from the Insights for specific components and display elsewhere?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely use the [`Application Insights REST API`](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/). Even though you will not be able to get the results of user flows for a specific components. you might have to query the data and build [your logic](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/apiexplorer/metrics?appId=DEMO_APP&apiKey=DEMO_KEY&metricId=requests%2Fduration&timespan=PT6H&interval=PT1H).